# How did I get a Mortarboard badge when I've only earned 95 rep for the whole month?

Tags: support, status-completed, badges, daily-reputation-badges

I was awarded the Mortarboard badge for [my SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2541/sam-hasler) today, but I've only received 95 rep for the whole month. Why did I get it?

Comment: Given that there was a rep recalc today that could have triggered it.

Comment: Sorry for OT. Chris, Please post your answer again on my question as recalc was the reason for my badge to disappear.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The badge was incorrectly accounting for deleted questions/answers, with a little bit of confusion added by the giant recalc that happened over the weekend.

The good news is; you no longer have this incorrect badge! woo! (that is success, right?)

Comment: and there was much rejoicing, yay. Although I just got it on meta and I shouldn't have it here either.

Answer (score 6):

This badge is retroactive, so if you earned it at any point in the life of your account, you will get it.

This can also be affected by retroactive deletions (posts + users + votes).

See https://stackoverflow.com/reputation for more.

Comment: nope. I've never hit the rep cap according to that page: "days represented 386,
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days,
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days"

Comment: some rough calculations on [stackoverflow api](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/2541/reputation?fromdate=0&page=1&pagesize=100) says that he got 550 reps on 2/24, 261 on 2/13, 300 on 2/10, 255 on 1/17. Could that be issue?

Comment: looking again @sam, you earned 238 rep on 2008-09-30 but 110 of that was on a deleted post (#153259) so we think this is a bug where the badge is not checking deletion state of the underlying post the votes are on.

Comment: thanks, that explains it, and it looks like it's been fixed, although I have the mortarboard badge on meta now....

Comment: Does this imply badges might be revoked when doing a manual recalc?