# My 'Mortarboard' badge just disappeared?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, badges

I don't know when exactly, but in the span of last 3-4 days, my Mortarboard disappeared from my profile. Badges look good after your name, and I have only a few, so losing one hurts :P

Can I know why the badge got removed.

Thanks for any replies.

Regards,
Yogesh.

Comment: I think recalculation was the reason behind it after all. I will request the first answerer to post the answer again so that I can accept it as I was wrong about the reputation being not low. I got to know about this by the `\repuation` report.

Comment: Answer undeleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because of the [rep recalc that happened recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80862/sudden-sharp-reputation-drop-problem-points-disappeared-and-score-lost-recalc/80865#80865) in preparation for the new `\users` page.

If an answer was deleted (question deleted, migrated etc.) that had given you enough votes to hit the cap then the badge will be removed.

Comment: Chris, the strange thing is that my reputation is exactly the same. No change at all. If there was a recalculation, my reputation would have gotten affected too.

Comment: @Yogesh - that changes things then. What does your `/reputation` report say at the bottom?

Comment: I think you are right. I checked `/reputation` and I have no entry of 200 (2 entries of 190). I think my reputation must have been recalculated too and somehow I don't recollect the correct value. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: It doesn't matter a lot, @Yogesh, but I doubt the recalc itself was the cause. The total reputation does not need to change for erroneous badges to be removed.

Comment: Arjan, I got 200+ rep on a certain day which I remember, so the badge was not erroneously awarded. I deleted a question with 3 upvotes due to some reason, so it was indeed a recalc.

Comment: @ChrisF, @Yogesh - Rep recalcs don't remove these badges, this was a separate fix for erroneously awarded badges around the same time (the past few days).

Comment: @Nick - I didn't mean to imply that it was. I deleted my answer after Arjan posted his (at it was better). I only reinstated it at the request of the OP.

Comment: @ChrisF - No worries, just trying to add information here since there's so much angst around the recalcs in general.  Just to be clear these were separate events, it just happened that we noticed a bug in this badge when looking at rep-ish things around the same time and it was fixed...as were the awards of it.  The recalc (for the new `/users` page, still underway) just happened to be time around the same....by itself it removes none of the badges on the badges page.

Answer (score 2):

It might [have been *awarded* erroneously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80907/how-did-i-get-a-mortarboard-badge-when-ive-only-earned-95-rep-for-the-whole-mont/80977#80977), and then will have been taken away now.

(Does your reputation report indicate you ever hit the daily cap?)

Answer (score 1):

Well to speak honestly, a friend of mine voted up many of my answers/questions in a short time :) and I hit 200 in one day, earned the badge etc. Then the next day everything was undone... So I imagine SO is "smart" by not allowing one user to boost up another another user's stats during a short amount of time.

It seemed like a good idea at the time though :D

Comment: Yes, this would also get hit in a rep recalc because those votes would have been deleted.  Sock puppetry (one account propping up another) is detected and dealt with.

Comment: Yep, I can verify personally that I lost all rep from that :)