# What happens if the badge criteria no longer sustains?

Tags: discussion, badges

What if we get a badge no matter  silver,bronze or gold after completing some criteria.What if the criteria does not hold now?

Mean to say:

> let's say i got a badge "nice question" after getting 10 upvotes . Now someone downvotes my question.Will that badge be gone?
>
> Or
>
> I got a enlightened badge but after which a better answer comes in and OP changes the accepted answer. What happens to my badge?
>
> or
>
> About unsung hero badge. I got about 20 accepted answers with 10(or 4 +) of which have zero score. So, I get a unsung hero badge . Now I post more accepted with positive score such that zero score answers gets reduced from 20% to 10%.Will my badge be taken back?

Comment: Badges are never removed (unless in extreme circumstances).

Comment: (regarding your edit below), `-----` is the markdown way of creating an hr, try not to use `<hr>`

Comment: @Manishearth It's one of the html tag I remember , so I use it frequently. `:P`

Comment: @Manishearth How the Note **This question may already have an answer here** comes on top of the question even before it's stated duplicate?It doesn't happen in any other site.

Comment: @exploringnet - Because your question is marked as duplicate.

Comment: @hims056 Not till now.... **[duplicate]** does not come written along with the question statement in head?

Comment: @exploringnet - While the question is still open, [only the OP sees the message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/167980/152859) and it becomes visible to everyone once the question gets closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the exception of tag badges, you keep whatever badge you earned - even if you no longer meet the criteria.

---

There are some rare cases, where a badge will be manually removed when there is fraud involved. But those are rare scenarios, and are only done in extreme circumstances.

Comment: Can you share some examples of those badge reversals?

Comment: @exploringnet: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80907/how-did-i-get-a-mortarboard-badge-when-ive-only-earned-95-rep-for-the-whole-mon/80977#80977, for example (this wasn't fraud, but a bug).

Comment: @exploringnet Here's one example of a badge reversal due to fraud: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130135/169611